# add filter on barcode image before scanning via zxing library

Tags: java, android, android-camera, zxing, barcode-scanner

i'm using `zxing` library for detecting barcodes.

in some images zxing cant detect barcode like this:

[image]

but when the `sharpen filter` add on image with photoshop the `zxing` detect barcode as well. like this:

[image]

can i add any filter on image before zxing detection level?

here is my code:

```
public class ScanFragment2 extends Fragment {

    private ViewGroup contentFrame;
    private ZXingScannerView zXingScannerView;

    private ArrayList<Integer> mSelectedIndices;
    private int camId, frontCamId, rearCamId;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        initVar();
        zXingScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(getActivity());
        setupFormats();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scan, container, false);


        initView(rootView);
        initListener();

        return rootView;
    }

    private void initVar() {
        camId = AppPreference.getInstance(getActivity()).getInteger(PrefKey.CAM_ID); // back camera by default
        if (camId == -1) {
            camId = rearCamId;
        }

        loadCams();
    }

    private void initView(View rootView) {
        contentFrame = (ViewGroup) rootView.findViewById(R.id.content_frame);

    }


    private void initListener() {


        zXingScannerView.setResultHandler(new ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handleResult(Result result) {

                String resultStr = result.getText();

                //this is my result: resultStr
                zXingScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);



            }
        });

    }

    private void activateScanner() {
        if (zXingScannerView != null) {

            if (zXingScannerView.getParent() != null) {
                ((ViewGroup) zXingScannerView.getParent()).removeView(zXingScannerView); // to prevent crush on re adding view
            }
            contentFrame.addView(zXingScannerView);

            if (zXingScannerView.isActivated()) {
                zXingScannerView.stopCamera();
            }

            zXingScannerView.startCamera(camId);
        }
    }


    public void setupFormats() {
        List<BarcodeFormat> formats = new ArrayList<>();
        if (mSelectedIndices == null || mSelectedIndices.isEmpty()) {
            mSelectedIndices = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < ZXingScannerView.ALL_FORMATS.size(); i++) {
                mSelectedIndices.add(i);
            }
        }

        for (int index : mSelectedIndices) {
            formats.add(ZXingScannerView.ALL_FORMATS.get(index));
        }
        if (zXingScannerView != null) {
            zXingScannerView.setFormats(formats);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        activateScanner();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (zXingScannerView != null) {
            zXingScannerView.stopCamera();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setMenuVisibility(final boolean visible) {
        super.setMenuVisibility(visible);
        if (zXingScannerView != null) {
                zXingScannerView.setFlash(false);
        }
    }


    private void toggleCamera() {

        if (camId == rearCamId) {
            camId = frontCamId;
        } else {
            camId = rearCamId;
        }
        AppPreference.getInstance(getActivity()).setInteger(PrefKey.CAM_ID, camId);
        zXingScannerView.stopCamera();
        zXingScannerView.startCamera(camId);
    }


    private void loadCams() {
        int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
            Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
            if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                frontCamId = i;
            } else if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
                rearCamId = i;
            }
        }
        AppPreference.getInstance(getActivity()).setInteger(PrefKey.CAM_ID, rearCamId);

    }


}
```

and the UI:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />




</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The ZXing library seems to be abstracting connecting to camera and getting preview stream. The sharpening is possible either if the library supports such argument or if it takes `Surface` or `SurfaceView` as input. In latter case you could configure two Surface one with input from Camera2, then sharpen each frame and then provide it as input to second surface.

Comment: Thanks for help. can you help me to find any sample or tutorial?